# Jquery mobile Nav bar to side bar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

i have created a simple sticky navbar using the following link

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Now the Navbar is always positioned horizontally. I want the navbar to position vertically. Is there a simple way of doing this. I dont want to use additional plugin's. A simple  css or a jquery code to position the nav bar like the list icon view.

I am trying to achieve the  navigation bar as in this link

https://www.paultrifa.com/~enabled1/envato/themeforest/side/blue/preview/

Regards,

Maclean Maurice pInto

Comment: why don't you just use listview?

Comment: because i want to use the default icon view of jquery mobile that is available with navbar

Comment: you always can use those icons, irrespective whether you use navbar or not. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Comment: list view does not provide. I tried. I am not getting any icons

Comment: does my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: I used Ur concept of anchor tags instead of un-ordered list and created a nav bar of buttons. working very well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-role="page">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content"> 
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>    

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <a data-icon="grid" data-role="button" href="#">abc</a>
      <a data-icon="star" data-role="button" href="#">abc</a>
      <a data-icon="gear" data-role="button" href="#">abc</a>
    </fieldset>
  </div><!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```